# FatalErrorException on AppKernel.php in Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony

I copied my project locally to the server and run it gives me this error:

> FatalErrorException: Error: Class 'Acme\IniciBundle\IniciBundle' not
>   found in /var/www/gesalight/gesaudit2/app/AppKernel.php line 19

Here my AppKernel:

```
<?php

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel;
use Symfony\Component\Config\Loader\LoaderInterface;

class AppKernel extends Kernel
{
    public function registerBundles()
    {
        $bundles = array(
            new Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\FrameworkBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\SecurityBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\TwigBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\MonologBundle\MonologBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\SwiftmailerBundle\SwiftmailerBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\AsseticBundle\AsseticBundle(),
            new Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\DoctrineBundle(),
            new Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\SensioFrameworkExtraBundle(),
            new Acme\IniciBundle\IniciBundle(),
            new Acme\ClientBundle\AcmeClientBundle(),
            new Acme\CatalegBundle\AcmeCatalegBundle(),
            new Acme\UsuariBundle\AcmeUsuariBundle(),
            new Acme\ProjectesBundle\AcmeProjectesBundle(),
            new Acme\AdminBundle\AdminBundle(),
            new Acme\ErrorBundle\AcmeErrorBundle(),
            new Acme\InventariBundle\AcmeInventariBundle(),
            new Ps\PdfBundle\PsPdfBundle(),
            new Acme\GisBundle\GisBundle(),
            new Acme\TaskFlowBundle\TaskFlowBundle(),
            new Knp\Bundle\SnappyBundle\KnpSnappyBundle(),
            new Acme\CorreuBundle\CorreuBundle(),
            new Acme\SectorsBundle\SectorsBundle(),
        );

        if (in_array($this->getEnvironment(), array('dev', 'test', 'prod'))) {
            $bundles[] = new Symfony\Bundle\WebProfilerBundle\WebProfilerBundle();
            $bundles[] = new Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\SensioDistributionBundle();
            $bundles[] = new Sensio\Bundle\GeneratorBundle\SensioGeneratorBundle();
        }

        return $bundles;
    }

    public function registerContainerConfiguration(LoaderInterface $loader)
    {
        $loader->load(__DIR__.'/config/config_'.$this->getEnvironment().'.yml');
    }
}
```

Here my IniciBundle class file (on src/Acme/):

```
<?php

namespace Acme\IniciBundle;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Bundle\Bundle;

class IniciBundle extends Bundle
{
}
```

The error only appears on the server, in my local computer works fine and it's the exactly same directory with the same files on it.

Any suggestion?

Comment: You tell "Here my IniciBundle class file (on `src/Acme/`):" while your namespace is `Acme\IniciBundle`, then your bundle should be in `src/Acme/IniciBundle/AcmeIniciBundle.php`

Comment: The file is called as IniciBundle.php and it is at the src/Acme/IniciBundle/IniciBundle.php path?

Comment: The main class of IniciBundle is called IniciBundle.php and his path is: `src/Acme/IniciBundle`